# SQL : 2 columns in 1 in result set

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Let's say I have 3 tables :

**info_contact :**

```
 id_contact     id_demand       email 
     1             1        contact1@a.com
     2             2        contact2@a.com
     3             3        contact3@a.com
```

**demand :**

```
 id_demand   date   
     1       2016-10-12     
     2       2016-11-05    
     3       2016-12-12
```

**invitation :**

```
 id_invitation  id_demand   partner_company  concurrent_company
     1             1             google           facebook
     2             1              null            linkedin
     3             2             google             null
     4             2              null             yahoo
     5             3             google             null
```

I would like to have that kind of result :

```
     Company  |   id_demand 
     ----------------------
     Facebook |      1
     Google   |      1
     Google   |      2
     Google   |      3
     Linkedin |      1
     Yahoo    |      2
```

with no difference between partner_company and concurrent_company (together in the result).

For the moment I have tried :

```
SELECT i.partner_company, d.id_demand
FROM info_contact as c, demand as d, invitation as i
WHERE c.id_demand = d.id_demand AND d.id_demand = i.id_demand
AND i.partner_company IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY i.partner_company, d.id_demand;
```

and

```
SELECT i.concurrent_company, d.id_demand
FROM info_contact as c, demand as d, invitation as i
WHERE c.id_demand = d.id_demand AND d.id_demand = i.id_demand
AND i.concurrent_company IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY i.concurrent_company, d.id_demand;
```

and I don't know how to combine these 2 queries and obtain the result that I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `UNION ALL`

```
select partner_company , id_demand
From invitation 
Where partner_company is not null
Union All
select concurrent_company , id_demand
From invitation 
Where concurrent_company is not null
```

Also I did not `JOIN` the other tables since you are not selecting them. If you want to check the existence then `JOIN` it. Use `INNER JOIN` syntax to join the table